# Having trouble with PDO queries (Notice: Undefined index)

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to extract a data from database, I'm using PDO to do it.

I have the following PHP code without success:

```
public function CheckIdentity($email, $password) {
    $usersArray = [];

    $SQL = " SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."' ";
    $resultBySQL = $this->dbConnected->query($SQL);

    while ($row = $resultBySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //$row = $resultBySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername($row['username']);
        $user->setEmail($row['email']);
        $user->setPassword($row['password']);
        $user->setRole($row['role']);
        $user->setPersonalInfo($row['personal_info']);
        print_r($user);

        array_push($usersArray, $user);
    }
}
```

When I print it, I'm getting the following (for each attribute):

`Notice: Undefined index: email`, etc, etc...

Also, when I only apply `$row = $resultBySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

I'm always getting this:

```
User Object ( [username:User:private] => [email:User:private] => [password:User:private] => [role:User:private] => [personalInfo:User:private] => )
```

By the way, I've tried to apply a code where I had good result:

```
foreach ($resultBySQL as $row) { /* Extract the info */ }
```

But now, with this example... It doesn't work.

On the other hand, I've checked the query in the database and the PDO connection, they're working without problem.

What is wrong? Do you have any idea?

Comment: put error_reporting(1) at the top to check for error

Comment: I don't have idea about this, I'm checking this right now. Thank you @anujnehra!

Comment: please use prepared statements and placeholders instead of  `".$email."`, What is the value of `$email` and `$password` does this data exist in the database, is you connection open etc.  What errors do you get.  Is this in a class, it looks like it is.  Is it namespaced? if so you need `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: I've checked it and I'm getting this:  Notice: Undefined index: email, etc, etc...

Comment: post what you are getting

Comment: add `var_dump($row);exit;` right inside the while loop and you will find your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
$row = $resultBySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

you are fetching all the results in one time, and you get an array of array. Since yor're making this call in your while condition, you're creating the whole result's array in the first iteration, then  the code exits in the second iteration, as there is nothing more to fetch, because all the results have already been fetched in the first iteration.

You should use:

```
//notice the 'fetch' in place of 'fetchAll'
while ( $row = $resultBySQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ) 
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($row['username']);

    //...
}
```

to fetch only one row for every iteration, then you can access its content inside the while loop

Alternatively, you could fetch all the rows once, an then loop through the results:

```
$rows = $resultBySQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach( $rows as $row )
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($row['username']);

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `fetch` instead of `fetchAll` in situations like this.